# do i will lose data in database if i delete migration files in django?

Tags: django, migration, migrate

I have Django Project and I want to add some table in my database but I'm not able to add it because I have some Problem in Migrations files , Do I will lose my data in database if I removed all migrations files

Comment: Why not try out and see what happens? As far as I see, the only thing to loose is bootstrapping the database, as this cannot be done from migrations. If you have "problems" in these files, why not fix the problems instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into your database schema.

So, deleting migration files does not affect the data in the database.
For more information look into django's [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/).